# How can I disable shift + control + scroll zoom in chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I use <kbd>⌃ ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd> + <kbd>⇥ tab</kbd> to move between tabs in Chrome, but if I scroll with the touchpad it'll zoom the page. This happens quite a lot and it's frustrating. Is there some way I can disable the <kbd>⌃ ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd> + <kbd>scroll</kbd> shortcut?

This is what happens:

[image: Video]

Comment: Zooming is a OS X system-wide function and not directly related to Chrome. Do you want to disable it totally?

Comment: @patrix It's not a system wide zoom. The system wide zoom is control + scroll. This only affects chrome, firefox and safari or any other application I try doesn't do it. It also only zooms the webpage, not the browser chrome or any such.

Comment: @patrix I've recorded a video on what happens.

Comment: I also have this exact problem and am looking for a solution…
Looks like we have a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=178972)

Answer (score 1):

If I might say so, why are you using the 3 keys to switch between the tabs.

In Chrome it is enough if you use two keys to switch tabs.

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>

If however you prefer to modify the the Chrome shortcuts, visit this website

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcut-manager/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf

Comment: I'm using 3 keys because it performs a different function. shift+ control + tab goes backwards.

Comment: The chrome extension you linked doesn't deal with combinations of mouse and keyboard as a shortcut, and doesn't solve the issue at all.

Comment: I wasn't thanking you, what you wrote didn't solve the issue. Also this isn't an OS X hotkey function, it's specific to chrome. It would be helpful if you would  attempt your own suggestions before answering so it is at least relevant.

Comment: Chrome does control what it wants to do when it detects user actions, this zooming feature doesn't come from OS X. If you look at the video I recorded you can clearly see it's not an OS X function. I've submitted this as a bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=230752 to chromium which they seem to think is a regression. I was not asking about creating shortcuts, I'm asking about removing one that is native to chrome.

Comment: OK, let see what they come up with.

Comment: I was looking for this too. This seems to happen on newer version of Chrome only. Previously, ctrl+shift+2finger scroll on trackpad did not trigger zooming.